# CSV to XML transformation fails in Saxon when special characters are present

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, saxon

I am evaluating [Andrew Welch's CSV to XML-Converter in XSLT 2.0](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html):

It works for me so far if I convert a CSV with no special characters like this:

```
ID,    Title, Type
152733,Test1,Type1
152757,Test3,Type2
152759,Test4,Type2
```

But if I try to convert a CSV with a German "Umlaut" like this:

```
ID,    Title,Type
152733,Test1,Type1
152757,Test3,Type2
152759,Täst4,Type2
```

the output is `"Cannot locate : test12.csv".`

So it seems to me the function `fn:unparsed-text-available` does not work if the text contains special characters. Any idea how to fix this?

Saxon version is Saxon-HE 9.7.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the file encoding to `unparsed-text()`.

I'm making an educated guess<sup>(*)</sup> here:

```
<xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($pathToCSV, 'Windows-1252')" />
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> UTF-8 is the default for the `$encoding` parameter of `unparsed-text()`. That means if reading the file fails then it clearly isn't UTF-8, but in a legacy (i.e. single-byte) encoding. German umlauts suggest the file was created in a typical "Western Europe" configuration, where either `Windows-1252` or `iso-8859-1` are the default legacy encodings.

Comment: Thank you, adding the encoding Windows-1252 to unparsed-text() and unparsed-text-available() did the job!

Comment: There is a large overlap but also subtle differences between `Windows-1252` and `iso-8895-1`, be sure to pick the right one. Wikipedia has a nice overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I already found out that only Windows-1252 does the job because the CSV not only contains umlaut, but also indent (this longer minus-character which MS Word automatically creates if you put a "-" into your text.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the tell-tale characters. (File being created on Windows is of course also a pretty strong hint.)